# Clearing many users' auto-complete list

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

Is it possible to clear many users' mail-recipient-cache, and how?

By "mail-recipient-cache", I mean the auto-complete list that shows when you are entering the recipients e-mail.

I know Outlook 2003/2007 stored these values in some .nk2 file, but now they're stored on the server?

The following stands true:
- EWS communication via c#
- Exchange Server 2010

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about doing this server-side however on the client-side:

You can delete all cached entries using Outlook command-line switch. Close Outlook, go to **Start** > **Run** > type `outlook.exe /cleanautocompletecache` and hit **Enter**. On Outlook startup, choose your Exchange profile. It will be loaded without cached entries.

Comment: Thanks. Problem is, there are about 1000 users. And some use online version only.

Comment: Ahh well yeah I can see how that would be a pain.  Sorry I couldn't help further